# Python on Windows: How to create accessible label for wx.ListCtrl widget using wxPython?

Tags: python, windows, wxpython, accessibility, screen-readers

In Python 3.10.5 on Windows 11 using the wxPython 4.2.0 package, I am trying to create a labelled `wx.ListCtrl` widget, where the widget label would be recognised by screen readers, but I cannot find the way to do so. So far, I have the following code:

```
hbox = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)
label = wx.StaticText(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, 'My label')
hbox.Add(label, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)
list = wx.ListCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY)
hbox.Add(list, 1, wx.EXPAND | wx.ALIGN_LEFT | wx.ALL, 5)
```

If I use the code above, both the label and list are created, but they seem not to be tied together, as when the list widget is focused, screen reader narrates only "List view", ignoring the label. However, if in the same code I replace `wx.ListCtrl` with `wx.ListBox`, the label starts to be narrated without an issue. But I need to use `wxListCtrl`, not `wx.Listbox`.

How can I label the `wx.ListCtrl` widget properly from the accessibility perspective, so that when focused with the screen reader, the label for the widget would be narrated?

Answer (score 1):

So there is a workaround for labelling [wx.ListCtrl](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.ListCtrl.html) widgets, which is acceptable by me, at least from the screen reader user's point of view. That solution lies in wrapping of the wx.ListCtrl widget with a [wx.StaticBox](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.StaticBox.html) or [wx.StaticBoxSizer](https://docs.wxpython.org/wx.StaticBoxSizer.html) object like [described here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73446177/python-on-windows-how-to-enclose-widgets-in-wxpython-to-labelled-group-similar). The code then  might look like this:

```
panel = wx.Panel(self)
box = wx.StaticBoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL, panel, 'Your lable for the list goes here')
list = wx.ListCtrl(box.GetStaticBox(), wx.ID_ANY)
box.Add(list)
panel.SetSizer(box)
```